# save all rows of gridview to database asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I have a gridview with two columns one of them is template field with dropdown list.. I want to save all rows to the database with a save button outside the gridview, but when I click it is saves only the first row of the gridview.. How Can I save the entire gridview to the database ??

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < GridView2.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                    GridViewRow row = GridView2.Rows[i];

                    string coursecode = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
                    string weekno = DropDownList2.SelectedValue.ToString();
                    string day = DropDownList3.SelectedValue;
                    string stid = row.Cells[0].Text;
                    DropDownList ddlstatus = (DropDownList)row.Cells[1].FindControl("DropDownList9");
                    string status = ddlstatus.SelectedValue.ToString();

                    double percentage;
                    if (status == "A")
                    {
                        if (day == "Saturday")
                        {
                            percentage = 6.66;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            percentage = 3.33;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        percentage = 0;
                    }


                    String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
                    String query = "insert into Attendance values (@CourseCode, @St_ID, @WeekNo, @Day,@Status, @Percentage)";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CourseCode", coursecode);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WeekNo", weekno);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Day", day);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@St_ID", stid);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", status);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Percentage", percentage);
                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                    Response.Redirect("~/DoctorAddEditAttendance.aspx");
                }
            }
```

Comment: It is because you `Redirect` inside the loop. But if you used databinding you would make it much easier .

Comment: Solved, thank you. can you please write your answer so i can marked as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `Redirect` outside of the loop so you finish processing all rows.

Incidentally, it is better practice to redirect this way:

```
Response.Redirect("~/DoctorAddEditAttendance.aspx", false);
Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```